# Upvoted, broken link-only answer with auto-attributed bounty

Tags: discussion, bounty, link-only-answers, broken-link

Should [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6515659/4957418) now deleted answer, which was upvoted and had an auto-attributed bounty, but essentially was link-only, be deleted like any other link-only answer, or could it possibly be useful for anyone.

Breaking down the post leaves us with:

> Define a custom EntityResolver.

Comment: Looks like it is already deleted?

Comment: @Turnerj yep, it seems it (along with another broken-link-only answer) was cleaned up already.

Comment: I'm probably in the minority with my option, but I think most answers like this should be deleted because they're basically link-only answers. At best they're extremely lacking in detail and would be better off as a comment if the effort to at least explain the basic usage is too much to ask.

Answer (score 2):

This "They defined a custom EntityResolver for that"(+ some link) is perfectly acceptable answer in general - it is definitely not link-only answer, nor "not an answer". For some question it may even deserve upvote, but for most questions such amount of information (link + one sentence) is at best deserves no votes and sometimes should be downvoted.

Note that I can't judge particular Q&A pair - answer (already deleted) looks at least related to question to me, but that is way outside of my knowledge to make any better call.